# Something is wrong in a constructor of a class

Tags: java, constructor, this

This program requires for a user to enter twice of name and employmentId, while it has to require just once.

I am trying to print a sentence using name and employmentId instance variables which are inherited to a class named Nursing. The program ran well. However, the problem is that it requires a user to input twice for name and employmentId.

AbstractTest.java -

```
import java.util.*;

class AbstractTest {
    String name;
    int employmentId;

    AbstractTest (){
        //initialize name and employmentId instance variables
        System.out.println("enter name");
        Scanner readString = new Scanner(System.in);
        this.name = readString.nextLine();

        System.out.println("enter ID");
        Scanner readInt = new Scanner(System.in);
        this.employmentId = readInt.nextInt();
    }
    // constructor ends
}
```

Nursing.java -

```
class Nursing extends AbstractTest{
    void display() {
        System.out.println("the employment detail: " + "Name: " + 
        name + "ID: " + employmentId);
    }
}
```

Main.java -

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AbstractTest abstractTest = new AbstractTest();
        Nursing nursing = new Nursing();
        nursing.display();
    }
}
```

//It runs well, but it somehow repeats twice for inputting name and ID. it should require just once (below is the result from MS DOS).

**enter name**
Batman

**enter ID**
1234

**enter name**
Superman

**enter ID**
5678

the employment detail: Name: SupermanID: 5678

Comment: You should learn what constructors are supposed to do. You also don't need to create a new instance of Scanner each time you wish to read a value

Comment: You are creating two `AbstractTest` objects (one being `Nursing` which extends `AbstractTest`) and thus call the `AbstractTest` constructor twice. Maybe don't create the `abstractTest` variable?

Comment: Shouldn't `AbstractTest` be `abstract`? 

Comment: @Guy I think it's meant to be some kind of a test, for a reader most likely - to see if he realised it isn't actually an abstract class 

Comment: @Stultuske Thank you for the help. As I learned from a uni, a constructor is used for initializing instance variables in a class. If there are more purposes using a constructor, can you let me know? thank you!

Comment: @CalebHyun yes, but instantiating a Scanner inside a constructor is nonsense. this way, you make your class only usable by applications that are executed on a terminal. if you ever want to use that class in something different, a web service, for example ... good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the line

```
AbstractTest abstractTest = new AbstractTest();
```

Although you don't work with that object, it's being created and the `Scanner` is requesting 2 inputs.

```
Nursing nursing = new Nursing();
```

is enough: it will call its parent's constructor, which is the one of `AbstractTest`.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
Nursing nursing = new Nursing();
```

automatically calls the constructor of the super class, that is `AbstractTest()`. You don't have to call it explicitly by creating an object of `AbstractTest`

Thus, simply remove the line

```
AbstractTest abstractTest = new AbstractTest();
```

If you don't remove it, the constructor is run twice, and thus you have to give the input twice as well.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a `Nursing` object, it implicit empty construct calls the `super` no-args constructor. So `AbstractTest` constructor is being called two times - once when you create its object, and other when you create a `Nursing` object.

Object creation while using inheritance is a bit complex and I suggest you read on it.

Comment: I always forget ```super()``` is hidden in the first line of a class. Thank you Prashant.

Comment: No problem Caleb, just keep coding :)